# Launch Android Emulator with No Data via Command Line

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

I'm trying to figure out how to launch an emulator with no data connection or airplane mode, either one will work. Im testing my application against data loss, however I need this to be atomized. Therefore I'm trying either to launch the emulator with no data via command line, or write bash script to launch emulator, turn data off, then run Unit Test.

RESOLVED - Per Recommendations

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10
spawn telnet localhost 5554
expect "OK"
send "gsm data off\n"
send "quit\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do it could be to make an app that starts at boot and turns data off, then run the emulator and install the app. This does have potential for inconsistency however.

The other thing you can do to leave just the emulator without a network is to [telnet into the emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#telephony) and turn data off. To automate it, I made a simple (and crude) example using a batch file and vbscript to feed telnet the commands since my work machine is running Windows.

The batch file:

```
@echo off
emulator -avd YOURAVDNAMEHERE
timeout /t 10
telnet_turn_data_off.vbs
```

`telnet_turn_data_off.vbs`:

```
set oShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.Run "telnet localhost 5554", 9
WScript.sleep 500

oShell.Sendkeys "gsm data off{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 500

oShell.Sendkeys "gsm voice off{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 500

oShell.Sendkeys "quit{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 500

oShell.Sendkeys "quit{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 500
```

If running on Linux or Mac OS, [**expect**](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=30) should be able to script telnet (as seen by the edit to the question).

It is also worth noting that on older emulators (eg 2.2), [turning data off might not do anything](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3838). My above example was tested with a 4.2 emulator and it appeared to cut off data properly.

Comment: I've added what i believe was your suggestion however for expect on mac OS. you mind taken a quick look

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment Try to `expect "OK"` before every `send`.

Comment: Updated the script, we are getting so close. I've updated the code in the description. It seems to show the telnet commands, however no change on the emulator.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment Hmm, it seems once the "OK" is found, all the commands get sent, and it's likely none of them actually get executed (no recognizable syntax since everything is together). You should be fine with just `data off`, so see if keeping just that works.

Comment: Its still seems to not be working, its very strange. Doesnt seem to actually send the command to the device.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment try writing `send "gsm data off\n"` `send "quit\n"`

Answer (score 0):

I typically use physical hardware for testing instead of emulators, but if you can't find an option to enable airplane mode you could simply disconnect your computer from the internet before launching the emulator. No internet for your computer = no internet for your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Following steps..

Go to Eclipse

Window->show view->other->android->Devices
now select your running emulator and Again

Go to,

Window->show view->other->android->Emulator Control
Now in that..set Data to Unregister from Home

From Device and Emulator

In Device or Emulator Go to,

Setting -> Wireless & networks -> Airplane Mode -> ok